# Is declaring instance variables in JSP a good practice?

Tags: jsp

I'm doing a JSP/servlet project. Some of my teammates like to **store text messages which are used to render the page content in the string variables by `<c:set scope="page"/>`**. Is this a good practice? If not, what is the reason for not doing so?

Comment: try to avoid declaring variable in JSP.You may use JSTL tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call it bad practice, especially when using within the `page` scope.

```
<c:set var="myVariable" scope="page"
       value="${myBean.someProperty.anotherProperty}" />
Value of A is ${myVariable.a}
Value of B is ${myVariable.b}
Value of C is ${myVariable.c}
```

Is more readable than

```
Value of A is ${myBean.someProperty.anotherProperty.a}
Value of B is ${myBean.someProperty.anotherProperty.b}
Value of C is ${myBean.someProperty.anotherProperty.c}
```

However, if you are using this to store *text messages*, a better option would probably be to use a [Message Bundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) in your JSP und use that. `fmt` tags can be used for this.

Comment: Indeed, Grails use <g:set/> to implement the feature of localized messages.